# memcached set not stored

Tags: memcached, libmemcached

[image]

The following step has followed:

```
telnet localhost 11211
set Test 0 100 10
get Test 
CLIENT_ERROR bad data chunk
ERROR
set amit 2 2 2 
get amit 
CLIENT_ERROR bad data chunk
ERROR
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was providing the value but the bytes were not exactly what I was mentioning in the set command, for the format of the command is:

```
set KEY META_DATA EXPIRY_TIME LENGTH_IN_BYTES
```

so for those who were just copy pasting the command without knowing as to why is it not storing the key and came here for the answer, this might help:

You need to provide the value of exactly the same bytes which you have mentioned in the last parameter of the set command

the following won't work:

[image]

also the following won't:

[image]

So when you enter the value it has to be exactly the same bytes, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Although you do not ask a specific question, i presume you want to store a value.
You could test with the default example from the Memcached manual.

You define that you want to store a key, but don't specify a value.

The following example specifies that you want to save a key "tutorialspoint", no flags, timeout of 900 and reserve 9 bytes for a value. Those 9 bytes are specified in the next line: "memcached". In your example i don't see a value.

```
set tutorialspoint 0 900 9
memcached
STORED

get tutorialspoint
VALUE tutorialspoint 0 9
memcached

END
```

Comment: How to remove the error "CLIENT_ERROR bad data chunk".

Comment: As i said. With the "set Test 0 100 10" you specify that the next 10 characters will contain the value, but you do not give a value. Hence you do not get the confirmation 'STORED'. Although you did not set the value, you still try to retrieve something.

Answer (score 2):

‘set Test 0 100 10’, then enter a value which the length is equal to 10。

Answer (score 1):

the `set` command takes 4 arguments:

1. key - this is an arbitrary key you'll later use to retrieve the value
2. flag - use `0` for no flags
3. ttl - time to live in seconds.  this is how long memcache will hold your value.
4. size - in bytes.  Byte count of your value.

In my case I was neglecting to calculate the number of bytes and that was why I kept getting the "client error bad data chunk" error